# Цепочка в базе данных SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

Стоит задача сделать отображение базы данных на web-странице должным образом, подробнее ниже.Очень много вариантов пробовал,такие как JOIN,CONCAT, но до сих пор не могу найти то, что мне нужно.Выполняю задачу в SQL-сервер, одновременно и в phpmyadmin и в php, от безисходности.Вообщем нужно сделать некую цепочку связанных данных.Ниже на фото показано как это примерно выглядит.

Может кто то предложит не сложный вариант или подробно может объяснить?
Или же есть код?

Или же есть такой же вариант только по Айди как нибудь, допустим

1- 23/26/28/36/154
2- 54/67/88/96/110

Вместо цифр, то есть id, слова.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы уж определитесь, какая СУБД у вас, mysql или SQL Server

Comment: Такой способ хранения иерархических данных называется adjacency list - список смежности. Поиск по этим терминам выдаст способы написания sql-запросов для разных целей. / Также рекомендую ознакомиться с другими способами хранения иерархий в СУБД.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.id ,t.element + '-' + 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT st.element
                  ORDER BY st.element 
                  DESC SEPARATOR '-') 
FROM table t
JOIN secondtable st ON st.parentID = t.id
GROUP BY t.id, t.element
```

Comment: Вероятно secondtable надо на table заменить?

Comment: Я не знаю, использует ли он две таблицы или одну, тут же у меня нет четко расставленных данных